# how to delete all files that begin with 'testcase-' on a windows server?

Tags: windows, ms-dos

On a windows server, using a DOS command, how can I delete files in the current directoy that have the pattern like:

- testcase-234.html
- testcase-2322.html
- testcase-12.html

i.e. files that begin with testcase-xxx.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Umm `del testcase-*.html`

Answer (score 2):

```
del testcase-*.html
```

Is this a trick question?

Comment: You forget, it's been a very long time since the command prompt was actually required for use of an OS. It's quite possible that this user has honestly never had any use for it.

Comment: "it's been a very long time since the command prompt was actually required for use of an OS" - you might be surprised next time you try an Unix-based one.

Comment: I can't imagine managing an OS without a command prompt and scripting capability.

Comment: I've been using PowerShell so long I can't remember what cmd can actually do.